# JAX-WS SOAP Service freezes when server does not responses

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have implemented SOAP client from wsdl schema using JAX-WS wsgen tool.
This was done under Windows 32bit JDK 1.6.0_45, JAX-WS RI 2.1.6, Generated source version: 2.1

When service is does not responses, my code just hangs when trying to call Service constructor.

I have spent quite a long time looking for solution. I have found out: 
1) Adding timeout system properties like:

```
sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout=50
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout=50
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=50
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.readTimeout=50
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=50
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=50
timeout=50
```

2) Adding timeout properties to RequestContext of BindingProvider:

```
port = service.getExampleServicePort();
        BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
        prov.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", requestTimeout);
        prov.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", requestTimeout);
        prov.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", connectTimeout);
        prov.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", connectTimeout);
```

The problem is, that code freezes before I can get a port, particularly when I call the constructor of generated service class, which extends javax.xml.ws.Service :

```
   service = new ExampleService(url, new QName("http://query.services.example.com/", "ExampleService")); 
//freezes here
```

Here is the constructor which causes a problem:

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "ExampleService", targetNamespace = "http://query.services.example.com/", wsdlLocation = "http://myservicehost/services/Query.asmx?WSDL")
public class ExampleService
    extends Service
{

    public ExampleService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    //....
}
```

Finally, this method of Service just hangs

```
protected Service(java.net.URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName) {
        delegate = Provider.provider().createServiceDelegate(wsdlDocumentLocation,
                serviceName,
                this.getClass());
    }
```

How can I prevent my ExampleService from freezing when service does not respond (without using another libraries like Apache Axis or JBoss WS)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090111/how-can-i-generate-wsdl-file-from-wsdl-url) applies to your problem - save WSLD document locally.

Comment: Ok, this really helps. It turned out, that WSDL is needed to instantialize service class. This was described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21150088/3198526) answer. But what if WSDL will be changed and I use outdated local copy?

Comment: If someone changes WSLD in backwards compatible way(say adds new method or parameter that might be null) - that's still fine. If service contract would be changed in incompatible way(that's just sloppy) your client would be broken no mater whether you download WSLD or keep it locally.