# Is JAX-WS web service needs a wsdl file to generate client code?

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I have created JAX-WS web project which is working fine by generating client code using wsimport with wsdl url. But some of them needs wsdl extension files. Please any one help me to generate the wsdl file from a wsdl url.

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090111/how-can-i-generate-wsdl-file-from-wsdl-url) SO article: "Navigate to the URL in a browser and save the file it generates. You'll need to make sure you also save any schemas imported by the wsdl."

Comment: thank you for your replay. Is that correct method to generate wsdl file. That is showing xml extension when i save that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your WSDL url from a web browser, and then save the page.  You may be prompted to save the page with a `.xml` extension.  The reason for this is that all WSDL files are also a type of XML file.  Instead, manually change the extension of the file to `.wsdl`.  If you are prompted with a dialog box immediately after navigating to the WSDL file, then just save it right there AS a `.wsdl`

Comment: Is there possible to generate client stub with only .wsdl file (without running service)?